# Cold start of AWS Sagemaker Endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, endpoint, autoscaling

for my application I am using an AWS Sagemaker Async Endpoint, Lambda functions and an API Gateway. As the traffic is very sporadic I am using autoscaling, where I scale up the endpoint instance from 0 if someone connects to my Websocket Gateway and scale it down when the person disconnects. However, the scaling up is using a lot of time. Right now i am using the function below. But the endpoint scaling up (and also down) takes around 10 minutes.

I found the following documentation for the sagemaker_client.update_endpoint() function:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/update_endpoint.html

"Deploys the new EndpointConfig specified in the request, switches to using newly created endpoint, and then deletes resources provisioned for the endpoint using the previous EndpointConfig (there is no availability loss)."

So this would explain the long time it takes (I think the sagemaker_client.update_endpoint_weights_and_capacities() works in the same way?)

Does anyone has an idea, how to work around this long "coldstart" time?

```
def scale_up_sagemaker_endpoint(endpoint_name):
    """
    Scales up the specified SageMaker endpoint to have one instance.

    Parameters:
        endpoint_name (str): The name of the SageMaker endpoint to scale up.

    Returns:
        dict: The response from SageMaker API for updating the endpoint configuration.
    """
    sagemaker_client = boto3.client('sagemaker')

    try:
        # Get the current configuration of the endpoint
        response = sagemaker_client.describe_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name)
        current_instance_count = response['ProductionVariants'][0]['CurrentInstanceCount']
        variant_name = response['ProductionVariants'][0]['VariantName']
        print(variant_name)
        print(current_instance_count)
        
        if current_instance_count == 0:
            # If the current instance count is 0, scale up to one instance
            response = sagemaker_client.update_endpoint_weights_and_capacities(
                EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                DesiredWeightsAndCapacities=[
                    {
                        'VariantName': variant_name,
                        'DesiredInstanceCount': 1
                    },
                ]
            )
            print('scaled up')
            return response
        else:
            # No need to scale up if there are already active instances
            print('endpoint is already in use')
            print(current_instance_count)
            return {
                'message': f"Endpoint '{endpoint_name}' is already scaled up with {current_instance_count} instance(s)."
            }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'error': str(e)
        }
```

I also played around a little bit with this, but it wasn't faster / didn't really work properly:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/async-inference-autoscale.html
This could also be, because it is the fist time for me working with Sagemaker, so if this would in practice be the faster solution, please tell me so I can invest more time into this.